# place the results of a pg_query into a select dropdown box

Tags: php, html, postgresql, psql

i am running a pg_query which displays all the data in the uid column of a users table i have created.
What i need is for the results to be displayed in the usernameselect select dropdown box i have created and not on the html page. the code i have is below :

```
<?php 
    include_once 'newheader.php' ;
 ?>
 <!-- css for the page-->
 <section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2 class="page_title">New User</h2>
    </div>
<!-- dropdown list for all user names-->    
     <p>
What is your User Name?
<select name="Usernameselect">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="uid">'$row[0]'</option>  
</select>
</p>
  </section>  
<?php
// connect to database
$conn = pg_pconnect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv2 user=postgres");
if (!$conn) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}
// get all the uid from the uid column in users
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT uid FROM users");
if (!$result) {
  // error message  
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}
// dispaly on screen all uid data from users
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "$row[0]";
  echo "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well then you have to place the code that processes the result set where you currently have the `<option>` tags for that dropdown. **Obviously, you cannot access `$row` before you actually read the results from the query into $row**

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly i have placed the </option> </select></p>now at the end of the script, but it has placed all the data onto 1 line, what do i need to do make the user names be on separate lines?

Comment: All the data onto one line? Sorry I dont understand

Comment: When i click on the drop down instead of 1 line saying Dave next line John etc it is displaying all one one line i.e Dave John

Comment: I think maybe this is best asked as another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    include_once 'newheader.php' ;
 ?>
 <!-- css for the page-->
 <section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2 class="page_title">New User</h2>
    </div>
<!-- dropdown list for all user names-->    
     <p>
What is your User Name?
<select name="Usernameselect">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
<?php
// connect to database
$conn = pg_pconnect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv2 user=postgres");
if (!$conn) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}
// get all the uid from the uid column in users
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT uid,name FROM users");
if (!$result) {
  // error message  
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}
// dispaly on screen all uid data from users
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</p>
</section>
```